# How to clear digit arguments in a mapping?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript, count

I have a set of bindings for jumping to the (n*10)th column that are basically just sugar over the `|` command and somewhat nice for coarse horizontal movement.

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>`      0
nnoremap <silent> <leader>1     10\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>2     20\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>3     30\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>4     40\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>5     50\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>6     60\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>7     70\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>8     80\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>9     90\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>0    100\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>-    110\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader>=    120\|
nnoremap <silent> <leader><bs> 130\|
```

For the most part, it works well. However, I'll sometimes hit a stray digit by accident, say <kbd>1</kbd> and then hit <kbd>leader</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> and jump to column 120 by mistake.

Is there a way to modify the commands so that they clear numeric arguments before being executed?

I tried using the `normal` command to wrap one of the options

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>1 :normal "10\\\|"<cr>
```

(and several variations of backslashing to prevent the `|` from being interpreted as a line separator in the body of the `nnoremap`)

But doing that seems to be equivalent to <kbd>0</kbd> for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it:

- you need `<c-u>` to clear the count
- and then either you use quotes with `:exe`, or you use none

In short:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>1 :<c-u>exe 'normal! 10\|'<cr>
" or
nnoremap <silent> <leader>1 :<c-u>normal! 10\|<cr>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be to carry out the movement with a function. The existing `count` will be converted to a `range` on the command line, but we can clear this with `<C-U>`.

This has the slight advantage of allowing you to compress the numerical mappings down a little:

```
for i in range(1, 9)
  execute 'nnoremap <silent> <leader>'.i.' :<C-U>call cursor(0, '.i.'0)<CR>'
endfor

nnoremap <silent> <leader>` :<C-U>call cursor(0, 1)<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>0 :<C-U>call cursor(0, 100)<CR>
" etc
```

*(hat-tip to [Carpetsmoker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/carpetsmoker) and [B Layer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/11054/b-layer) for use of `cursor()` instead of the function originally in this answer).*

#### Further Reading

- `:help :call`
- `:help v:count`
- `:help cursor()`